# dealing with missing values

Tags: multiple-regression, missing-data

I am  analyzing the data of a cohort study. there are three sets of paired data (same measures on same subjects in 3 different point of time).  The problem is that the third set of data have more than 50% missing values.  My question is that, how can I deal with these missing values? does MI help in these repeated measures? it seems that if I delete the missing I loose more than half of my data set.